# Submitting a form for deleting data with route parameters only in asp net core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I am using asp net core and have a typical scenario to delete a record from my database and redirect back to detail view but i'm not sure if i'm doing it in a safe and best practice way.

**View form...**

```
<form asp-controller="Client" asp-action="DeleteSanction" asp-route-id="@Model.ClientSanctionID" asp-route-redirectid="@Model.ClientID">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-flat btn-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
```

**Controller action...**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteSanction(int id, int redirectId)
{

    if (await _dataClient.DeleteSanction(id) == false)
    {
        TempData["ToastType"] = "error";
        TempData["ToastContent"] = "Unknown database error";
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Detail", new { id = redirectId });
}
```

This is all working ok but it feels dodgy to be submitting a form without any form values and only using routing parameters.

**Question...**

Is it safe/good practice to submit a form and delete/update database records based on a route parameters and no form values only?

Comment: It makes no difference if the values are submitted in the url or the body of the request

Comment: Your controller is not subject to authentication ? It's a public function ? Are you in https ?

Comment: It's actually pretty standard. The point of doing the POST is simply that GET requests should be idempotent - nothing should ever be changed/modified/deleted via a GET. The POST just serves as confirmation and ensures that it's a deliberate act, rather than simply requesting the endpoint via GET.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmations. The controller is decorated with [Authorize] and https is enforced in startup too.